# I Can't Run a Java Module on Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

So I am very much a newcomer to the android studio, so I might've missed a few settings here and there, but
when I try to run a code with created java module, it doesn't recognize any of my code.

I attached the screenshot of what the ide returned to me.
[image]

I tried to reinstall the newest version of the android studio with the newest version of SDK (I attached another image file.) several times, but it doesn't seem to go anywhere. [image]

For the SDK tools, I have the followings:

- Android SDK Build-Tools
- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform-Tools

Also, I did try Build>Cealn Project.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

P.S. Here is my build gradle for the java module.
[image]

Comment: The entry point to an Android application differs to a Java application. Instead of a `main` method, you specify an activity with the `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` intent filter in your manifest. You should probably spend some time doing some tutorials on Android basics, as it is more complicated to run even a simple Android app versus a Java app.

Comment: Can you post your build gradle for the java module?

Comment: Kerry, 
I added my build gradle for the java module to the very end of my post. Thank you.